# Haskell- looping every second element of list

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I want to be able to loop every second element of a given list. I can do this recursively as so:

```
check validate (x:xs) = check (validate x) (tail xs)
```

But the problem is that I need a function that accepts a list as parameter, then returns a list consisting of only every second element in the list, starting with (and including) the first element of the list, and I do not think this is possible recursively.

Can someone show me how to this using list comprehension? This would probably be the best approach.

Comment: `snd . foldr (\x (b, xs) -> (not b, if b then x:xs else xs)) (True, [])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
second (x:y:xs) = y : second xs;
second _ = []
```

List comprehension may not be useful.

Comment: This seems good, but I need to save every element into a new list, is this possible?

Comment: In Haskell, any operation gives you a new "object". (Except when one explicitly deals with "unsafe" operations.) So all the solutions on this page till now have given you a new list. The reason is too long to write here, so please search for "what is functional programming" on the net.

Comment: you're right, but one more thing, I wanted to start with the first element. For example, if I had the list [1,2,3,4,5] I should get [1,3,5]

Comment: Change y on the right of "=" on the first line to x. Leave left of "=" unchanged.

Comment: @Abhay wouldn't you also need an extra pattern `second [x] = x`?

Comment: @genisage Yes, thanks, you are right, when we need elements from the first one. The original one above does not. Change: `second [x] = [x]`

Answer (score 7):

You can also try mutual recursion

```
first [] = []
first (x:xs) = x:second xs

second [] = []
second (x:xs) = first xs
```

such as

```
> first [1..10]
[1,3,5,7,9]

> second [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the Haskellish approaches would be something with `map`, `filter`, and `zip`.

```
second xs = map fst $ filter (odd . snd) $ zip xs [1..]
```

If you really wanted to use list comprehension, you could use the parallel list comprehension extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
second xs = [ x | (x, n) <- [ (x, n) | x <- xs | n <- [1..] ], odd n ]
```

I think that the former is concise, though.

Comment: if you wanted to use list comprehensions and you're fine with this zipping and unzipping stuff, why not use `[ fst x | x <- (zip xs [1..]), (odd $ snd x) ]`?

Comment: Just to make clear that you can replace `zip` with a parallel list comprehension as well as `map` and `filter` with an ordinal list comprehension.